# can't get sass command working on mac with 'brew install sass/sass/sass'

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, homebrew

I installed Ruby many moons ago but never use it. Perhaps I inadvertently broke it as I seem to be having troubles with getting it working with the sass command.

After running the `brew install sass/sass/sass` I get the following error with sass command:

```
rbenv: sass: command not found                                                                                      
The `sass' command exists in these Ruby versions:                                                                   
  2.1.10                                                                                                            
  2.5.0
```

ruby -v yields:

`ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]`

which I'm guessing is the stock version of Ruby on a mac.

The `rbenv` command prints out help so it looks like I have that installed. `brew list` shows I have the ruby package installed. I upgraded ruby with brew but that didn't help (it reported I upgraded from 2.6.1 to 2.6.2. I don't appear to have `rvm` installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM you shouldn't need to brew install anything, in fact you shouldn't.

See documentation here https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass which is deprecated and will refer you to use https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby instead.

`brew uninstall` any ruby and ruby packages and just use rbenv to manage your ruby versions.

Once you set your ruby version with `rbenv global 2.6.1` for example or whatever version you want, then just do

```
gem install sassc
```

Or in your Gemfile add

```
gem 'sassc`
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Ugh, looks like I'm in dependency hell: `Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.2
because it is required by vim, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby`. I think this could be from installing neovim. I dunno.

Comment: OK, well, I poked around the rbenv command a bit and set my ~/.rbenv/version file to 2.5.0 which did the trick. The sass command now works. I'll worry about straightening out my ruby install another day.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I saw tye error

```
rbenv: sass: command not found
```

during `rails new ...` for a rails 7.1 app.

My system version of node was `16`. I used `nvm use v20.9.0` to switch to a more recent version and tried `rails new ...` again and the problem was gone.